# How to mark record as exported in dynamic crm 2011 after the export into excel?te

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How to update the attribute exported to "ture" after export the several leads into an excel in the dynamic crm?

Comment: can you explain better your question?

Comment: I want to export the multiple leads to excel in the dynamic crm 2011. And I also want to mark the lead record which has been exported. How to do it ?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose behind doing this? That will us provide you a solution. I know I can think of multiple solutions to solve this need but each has limitations and its hard to know which is best without knowing the full business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A simple manual non-coded option would be to do a bulk edit within the same fetch that you use for the export!

Otherwise Java Script:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("CRMFieldName").setValue(Value);
```

Or try a plugin/ssis process to export.

Really we need more details on your business process here though.

what have you tried so far?